# JQuery slow image change

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 pictures.

```
 <div class="work-default-row">
     <img class="img1" src="/files/ourWork/titleImages/img1.jpg"/>
     <img class="img2"  src="/files/ourWork/titleImages/img2.jpg"/>
 </div>
```

In **CSS**

```
.work-default-row { 
     position:relative;
 }

.img1 {
     width:100%;
     height:400px;
 }

.img2 {
     position:absolute;
     top:0px;
     left:3000px;
     width:100%;
     height:400px;
 }
```

and **JavaScript**

```
$(".work-default-row").hover(function(){
    $(".img2", this).stop().animate({left:"0"},{queue:false,duration:200});
}, function() {
    $(".img2", this).stop().animate({left:"3000px"}, 
  {queue:false,duration:200});
});
```

It "works", on hover, the second image just came from nowhere and overlays the first image. But this solution is HORRIBLE.(The position of img1 is in the middle of page, So I can see how the img2 come from right through whole page and in resolution bigger than 3000px, user is able to see the second image)
Please, can somebody help me and tell me how can i make this images change effective?

Comment: What kind of transition do you need on hover? Have you considered to use css only instead of jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the width of the container you can set it to hide anything outside of it with.

```
#container_id{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

It looks like your using the `work-default-view` as your container.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```js
$(".slider").hover(
  function() {
    $(".slider-inner", this)
      .stop()
      .animate({ left: "0" }, { queue: false, duration: 200 });
  },
  function() {
    $(".slider-inner", this)
      .stop()
      .animate({ left: "-100vw" }, { queue: false, duration: 200 });
  }
);
```

```css
.slider{
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slider-inner {
  width: 200vw;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow:hidden;
}
img{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider-inner">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1538291397218-01e8830ddc68?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=fd07afd311ed4a74d0eed33089be01bb&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" />
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1538306196939-82f33cccacad?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=8c3ebd64083bb95f0b27c5d222b0f170&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing width of img2 instead of left.

```js
$(".work-default-row").hover(function() {
  $(".img2", this).stop().animate({
    width: "100%"
  }, {
    queue: false,
    duration: 200
  });
}, function() {
  $(".img2", this).stop().animate({
    width: "0"
  }, {
    queue: false,
    duration: 200
  });
});
```

```css
.work-default-row {
  position: relative;
}

.img1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

.img2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 0;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="work-default-row">
  <img class="img1" src="https://picsum.photos/200" />
  <img class="img2" src="https://picsum.photos/200" />
</div>
```